# Using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis Nuget package causes WACK to fail

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis, desktop-bridge

I am planning to publish my WPF app in Microsoft Store using Desktop Bridge. App is using .NET Compiler Platform ("Roslyn"). My problem is that the app is currently failing 2 WACK tests.

**Fail 1: Debug configuration.** 
Error Found: The debug configuration test detected the following errors:

```
The binary Microsoft.Build.resources.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary Microsoft.Build.resources.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.Globalization.Calendars.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary Microsoft.Build.resources.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.Xml.XmlDocument.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core.resources.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.IO.FileSystem.DriveInfo.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.Net.Ping.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.ComponentModel.Primitives.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core.resources.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.resources.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.Net.NameResolution.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.ComponentModel.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.Diagnostics.Process.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.Collections.Concurrent.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.Reflection.Primitives.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core.resources.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.Text.Encoding.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.Reflection.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.resources.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.IO.IsolatedStorage.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.Net.WebSockets.Client.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.Resources.Reader.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.Linq.Parallel.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.Collections.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.Linq.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.resources.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core.resources.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.resources.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.Diagnostics.Contracts.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core.resources.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.Collections.NonGeneric.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core.resources.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.Linq.Expressions.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.Runtime.Handles.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.Net.Security.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.Threading.Timer.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.resources.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core.resources.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary Microsoft.Build.resources.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary Microsoft.Build.resources.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary Microsoft.Build.resources.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core.resources.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.Runtime.CompilerServices.VisualC.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.resources.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.Runtime.Extensions.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.Security.Principal.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core.resources.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.Globalization.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary Microsoft.Build.resources.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core.resources.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core.resources.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary Microsoft.Build.resources.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.ObjectModel.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.Collections.Specialized.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary Microsoft.Build.resources.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.AppContext.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary Microsoft.Build.resources.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.Security.Claims.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.Console.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.resources.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.resources.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.IO.Pipes.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary Microsoft.Build.resources.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary Microsoft.Build.resources.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.Linq.Queryable.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.Security.Cryptography.Csp.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.IO.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.Dynamic.Runtime.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.Net.NetworkInformation.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.Resources.Writer.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.Net.Primitives.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.Net.Requests.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.Runtime.Numerics.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core.resources.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.Xml.XmlSerializer.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.IO.FileSystem.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core.resources.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.Threading.Thread.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary Microsoft.Build.resources.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.resources.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.resources.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core.resources.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.resources.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.Drawing.Primitives.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.resources.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.resources.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.Threading.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.Xml.XDocument.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.Net.WebSockets.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.resources.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.Xml.XPath.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.Reflection.Extensions.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.Threading.Tasks.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.Threading.ThreadPool.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary Microsoft.Build.resources.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives.dll is built in debug mode.
The binary System.Runtime.dll is built in debug mode.
```

Impact if not fixed: Microsoft Store doesn’t allow a debug version of an app.

**Fail 2: Blocked executables** 
Error Found: The blocked executables test has detected the following errors:

```
File CsToDartTranspiler.WPF\Microsoft.Build.dll contains a reference to a "Launch Process" related API kernel32.dll!CreateProcessW
File CsToDartTranspiler.WPF\Microsoft.Build.dll contains a reference to a "Launch Process" related API System.Diagnostics.Process.Start
File CsToDartTranspiler.WPF\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core.dll contains a reference to a "Launch Process" related API System.Diagnostics.Process.Start
File CsToDartTranspiler.WPF\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll contains a reference to a "Launch Process" related API kernel32.dll!CreateProcessW
File CsToDartTranspiler.WPF\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll contains a reference to a "Launch Process" related API System.Diagnostics.Process.Start
File Microsoft.Build.dll contains a blocked executable reference to "Microsoft\MSBuild".
File Microsoft.Build.dll contains a blocked executable reference to "MSBuild".
File Microsoft.Build.dll contains a blocked executable reference to "msbuild.exe".
File Microsoft.Build.dll contains a blocked executable reference to "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild".
File Microsoft.Build.Framework.dll contains a blocked executable reference to "MSBuild".
File Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll contains a blocked executable reference to "cmd.exe".
File Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll contains a blocked executable reference to "MSBuild".
File Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll contains a blocked executable reference to "MSBuild.exe".
File Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core.dll contains a blocked executable reference to "MSBuild".
File Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core.dll contains a blocked executable reference to "MSBuild.exe".
File Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core.dll contains a blocked executable reference to "cmd.exe".
File Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.Desktop.dll contains a blocked executable reference to "Msbuild".
File System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll contains a blocked executable reference to "DnX".
File System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.dll contains a blocked executable reference to "DnX".
File System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding.dll contains a blocked executable reference to "DnX".
File System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll contains a blocked executable reference to "DnX".
File System.Threading.dll contains a blocked executable reference to "DnX".
File System.Xml.XDocument.dll contains a blocked executable reference to "DnX".
File System.Xml.XmlSerializer.dll contains a blocked executable reference to "DnX".
File Microsoft.Build.resources.dll contains a blocked executable reference to "MSBuild".
File Microsoft.Build.resources.dll contains a blocked executable reference to "MSBuild.exe".
File Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.resources.dll contains a blocked executable reference to "MSBuild".
File Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core.resources.dll contains a blocked executable reference to "MSBuild".
File Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.resources.dll contains a blocked executable reference to "Reg".
```

Impact if not fixed: Launching executable files is restricted on Windows 10 S systems. Apps that rely on this capability might not run correctly on Windows 10 S systems.

I am not sure if the app will be rejected from Store because of "Fail 2" (personally I am not interested in Windows 10 S mode).

All modules in my app are built with Release configuration. Here is the packages.config of the module referencing Microsoft.CodeAnalysis:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis" version="2.8.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers" version="2.6.1" targetFramework="net461" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common" version="2.8.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp" version="2.8.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces" version="2.8.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic" version="2.8.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Workspaces" version="2.8.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.Common" version="2.8.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.AppContext" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Collections" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Collections.Concurrent" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Collections.Immutable" version="1.5.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Composition" version="1.2.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Composition.AttributedModel" version="1.2.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Composition.Convention" version="1.2.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Composition.Hosting" version="1.2.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Composition.Runtime" version="1.2.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Composition.TypedParts" version="1.2.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Console" version="4.3.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.Debug" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.StackTrace" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.Tools" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Dynamic.Runtime" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Globalization" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.IO.Compression" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.IO.FileSystem" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Linq" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Linq.Expressions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Reflection" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Reflection.Metadata" version="1.6.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Resources.ResourceManager" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Runtime" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.InteropServices" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Numerics" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms" version="4.3.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates" version="4.3.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Text.Encoding" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Text.Encoding.CodePages" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Text.Encoding.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Threading" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Tasks" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Thread" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.ValueTuple" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Xml.ReaderWriter" version="4.3.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Xml.XDocument" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Xml.XmlDocument" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Xml.XPath" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Xml.XPath.XDocument" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
</packages>
```

Simple test app for reproducing the issue: https://github.com/kinex/roslyn_test

How can I possibly fix these issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both Fail 1 and Fail 2 can be ignored especially because they are originated from modules developed by Microsoft. Those tests are only optional tests in WACK so your app will be accepted in Windows Store even if those tests fail. For details see [Windows Desktop Bridge app tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/windows-desktop-bridge-app-tests).

Some details about the reported fails:

**Fail 1**: All binaries *.resources.dll contain debug information due to an issue in some of the dependencies of Microsoft.CodeAnalysis nuget package (some discussion about the issue [here](https://github.com/dotnet/xliff-tasks/issues/60)). I don't know why other (executable) binaries like System.Collections.dll are reported to contain debug information, I assume it is some .NET Framework version related "feature". But luckily this can be ignored too.

**Fail 2**: Nothing can be done to fix these "issues". Microsoft.CodeAnalysis and related modules need to do what they need to do.

Answer (score 1):

The Windows App Certification Kit contains a number of tests that help ensure your app is ready to be published to the Microsoft Store.

> Fail 1: Debug configuration. Error Found: The debug configuration test detected the following errors:

According to  *Debug configuration test* section of [Windows Desktop Bridge app tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/windows-desktop-bridge-app-tests), the debug configuration test is for testing the app to make sure it is not a debug build and is not linked to any debug frameworks. To fix it, if you have already built with Release configuration, please check if you have the correct version of .NET framework installed.

> Fail 2: Blocked executables Error Found: The blocked executables test has detected the following errors:

This is belonged to  *Package Sanity tests*. For desktop bridge app, this test helps you build better Desktop Bridge Apps to run on Windows 10 S machines. For the Archive files usage error, you could try to remove the executable files from the archived files and do not use self-extracting archives to place executable files on disk. For the  Blocked executables warnings, if the flagged file(s) is part of your application, you may ignore the warning.

Details please check the  Corrective actions section of each test from [Windows Desktop Bridge app tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/windows-desktop-bridge-app-tests) document.

Comment: @sunteen-wu-msft How do I check if I have correct version of .NET framework installed? And what is the correct version?

Comment: @sunteen-wu-msft Could you please check my test app for reproducing the issue https://github.com/kinex/roslyn_test

Comment: @sunteen-wu-msft Problem is that both Fail 1 and Fail 2 are caused by NuGet packages developed by you (Microsoft). But after closer look at [Windows Desktop Bridge app tests](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/windows-desktop-bridge-app-tests) document I noticed that both Fail 1 and Fail 2 fall under the "Current optional tests" i.e. they will not be used to evaluate my app in Microsoft Store. You could have told me that immediately instead of copy/pasting me those useless "corrective actions". So I won't make any changes and try submitting my app to Store next.

Comment: Yes, these two exceptions are came from optional tests according to the document I gave you.  Since you didn't ask question about if you could submit to store with these exceptions so that I 'm kindly provide you suggestions for resolving. Although these exception may not have influences on submit but still indicate you may do somethings wrong. You could have asked issue clearly next time not only with exceptions.

Comment: The first sentence of my question is "I am planning to publish my WPF app in **Microsoft Store** using Desktop Bridge". Normally a failing WACK means the app is rejected from the Store. But in this case it is probably different. As those issues are not in my code, I don't care about failing WACK if my app is accepted to Store.

Comment: @kine So what about submit your package to store as a test first?

Comment: @barry Yes I have done that already. Waiting for the certification.....

Comment: Certification passed, app is in the Store now.